# Oracle12c R2 on Windows 10 starts only one of two instances. Manual start results in LRM-00109

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-12c, startup, windows-10

I have installed Oracle 12c R2 on my local Windows 10 (64 Bit) machine. For the installation I choose only to install the software.

After the installation I have used the tool that comes with the installation to create databases. After the first database was created and started I was able to connect to it without any problems.

But after I created a second database and restarted the machine only the newly created database was started.

The first database is not started on boot and I cannot start it using sqlplus. I get the error

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: Parameterdatei 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITDBNAME.ORA' konnte nicht ge┐ffnet werden
```

The said file does in fact not exist. But such a file does also not exist for the other database. The directory contains a `SPFILE<DBNAME>.ORA` though for both databases. As far as I know oracle uses this pattern `SPFILE<DBNAME>.ORA` when starting the database. If cant find said file it goes on to use `INIT<DBNAME>.ORA`.

I have created a INITDBNAME.ORA file and added the content:

```
SPFILE = 'D:\SPFILEDBNAME.ORA'
```

and tryed to start the database using `startup pfile = 'D:\INITDBNAME.ORA'`
but the result was a

```
ORA-00205: Fehler beim Identifizieren der Kontrolldatei
```

error. Also confusing was that if the pfile was inside the Oracle Directory the command failed saying it cannot access the file.

**EDIT**
After I have deleted both instances, rebooted and created both instances again I can currently access them both.

When I try to login to the first instance I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01116: Fehler beim Íffnen der Datenbankdatei 5
ORA-01110: Datendatei 5:
'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\INSTANCE\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_DPKMRD6L_.DBF'
ORA-27041: Datei kann nicht ge÷ffnet werden
OSD-04002: Datei kann nicht ge÷ffnet werden
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Zugriff verweigert
```

**EDIT**
The Mirosoft Service Manager reports both inscantec as runngin.

Setting ORACLE_SID does not make any difference. After the installation of both instances I can connect via

```
sqlplus sys@instance1 as sysdba
or 
sqlplus sys@instance2 as sysdba
```

But this goes well only for a short time. After couple of minutes it starts to throw ORA-01110 when I connect to the first instance.

The data files are not missing. They are in the location in which Oracle reports them missing.

Comment: Since this is on Windblows, you need to make sure the service for the database (see services.msc) is started.  And when you go to a command line to connect with sqlplus, you need to make sure the environment variable ORACLE_SID is set correctly for the particular db you wish to work with.  But your errors seem to indicate a data file has gone missing or is corrupt.

Comment: @EdStevens please see my last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem which was that the databases started by the Windows service manager were started with a user that appears not to have sufficient permissions.

This is confusing since I have selected the default setting while installing to use Oracles virtual user. This virtual user seems not to have write permission to some files of the database.

I have changed the user by which the services are started from Oracles virtual user to the Windows "Local System" option. Since that both databases are running seemingly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The database did not start with the service. First I checked the setting for the service using the Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows and configured the DB to start with the service start (by the way, I prefer the database to shut down immediately when the service is shut down).

But enabling the database to open at service start didn't solve the problem. Next I found that the folder `%ORACLE_HOME%\database` was read-only, and I did not succeed to clear this attribute using the properties dialog in the Windows Explorer. The `attrib` program showed no R flag, though...

It was not possible to start up the database as SYSDBA from sqlplus either - I got the same LRM-00109 error. So I copied the `SPFILE` to an `INIT<INSTANCE>.ora` file and edited it. Startup wasn't possible either, except when I used

```
startup open pfile='(ORACLE_HOME)\database\init(Instance).ora'
```

I finally changed the service from running as a virtual account to running as Local System - that works...

The Oracle version I use is 12.2.0.1 - I guess there is some problem with it.